# Selecting values from two tables

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables, `a` and `b`. Both tables contain a `config_data` column. `a` is in one database and `b` in another.

I want to select values from `a` that are not in `b`, as well as values that *are* in `b` but *not* in `a`.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT b.dim2 
FROM sakthi_a1.`config_data` AS a 
JOIN sakthi_a2.`config_data` AS b 
    ON a.dim2<>b.dim2 
GROUP BY b.dim2
```

It's not working. I need a query to solve this problem.

Just forget about the above query. It's wrong, I know.

I need to select a value from those tables based on the conditions given above. Is it possible?

**Sample data**

```
sakthi_a1.config_data
id  dim1 dim2                    config_value
1   site is_module_page          0
2   site default_html_header_tpl html_headedr.tpl
3   site facebook                test


sakthi_a2.config_data
id  dim1 dim2                    config_value
1   site is_module_page          0
2   site default_html_header_tpl html_headedr.tpl
3   site error                   Invalid page
```

Comment: If I lost a hair for every time I've seen `it's not working` without an error message, explanation of how it _should_ work, or any incorrect results, I'd be bald. Everywhere.

Comment: @JamWaffles: i fear that everywhere :D

Answer (score 1):

What about something like the following query:

```
(
    SELECT
        a.*
    FROM
        a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            b
        WHERE
            b.dim = a.dim
    )
)

UNION

(
    SELECT
        b.*
    FROM
        b
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            a
        WHERE
            a.dim = b.dim
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (rows in a that are not in b)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM sakthi_a1.`config_data` AS a 
LEFT JOIN sakthi_a2.`config_data` AS b 
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```